# complex left join sql query with 3 different key and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I would like to make a complex join

1. number fields are same in both table a and table b  line on table
2. line can be 1.000 at table A but at table B can be from 1.000 to 1.999 but it is same
3. quantity will reduce from table A if line exist on table b

is it possible directly with sql or I need to find something with PHP ?

[image: left join]

Comment: so what your saying is you want to join 2 tables with no key?

Comment: if you do not consider quantity. and if the line numbers are the same. It can be (tableA.number=tableB.number and tableA.line=tableB.line)

Comment: so the number and line will always be on both tables if the substraction should occur?

Comment: no just numbers are same. line 1000 on tableA can be from 1000-1999 at TableB.